# Get content between tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have and input like `<label><input type="checkbox" name="controls[]" value="1347438434" />50504762b6102</label>` and I need to get 50504762b6102.

Here full input:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="controls[]" value="1347438434" />50504762b6102</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="controls[]" value="1347438435" />50504762b61d9</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="controls[]" value="1347438436" />50504762b62af</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="controls[]" value="1347438437" />50504762b6385</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="controls[]" value="1347438436" />50504762b6466</label>
```

I also have an array `selected_ids` which stores selected values, for example *1347438434, 1347438436, 1347438436*.

So I am trying to get content like:

```
$.each(selected_cameras_ids, function(key, value){
    console.log($('input[value="'+value+'"]').nextUntil('label'));
});
```

But it returns empty object. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.parent()` to get the parent label and then use `.text()` to get the text content.

```
$.each(selected_cameras_ids, function(key, value){
    console.log($('input[value="'+value+'"]').parent().text());
});
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/heD46/)***

Answer (score 0):

Try this (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kjvUh/):

```
$.each(selected_cameras_ids, function(key, value){
    console.log($('input[value="'+value+'"]').parent().text());
});
```

Comment: as i said - i need text only after selected input.